# Add Fluent Migrator Migrate step after Team Foundation Service build has finished

Tags: azure, tfs, tfsbuild, fluent-migrator

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 app and I'm using the hosted Team Foundation Service to automate builds and deploy to an Azure WebSite.

This works great except for deploying the database changes.

I'm using Fluent Migrator to specify the changes to the database and currently I have a custom  implementation of IDatabaseInitializer so that when my Entity Framework context spins up, it does any migrations as necessary.  Obviously this leaves the database migration until 'first run' of the application rather than the build and deploy.

What I'd like to be able to do is get the build to attempt the migration before it deploys to azure (and therefore fail the build if there's a problem with the migration).

Is this possible with the hosted build service? Can I add post-build steps as I can with a self hosted inhouse TFS?

Comment: If TFS is using MSBuild you should be able to run FluentMigrator using the MSBuild runner - https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Migration-Runners#msbuild-runner.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your .csproj file:

```
  <UsingTask TaskName="FluentMigrator.MSBuild.Migrate" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\FluentMigrator.MSBuild.dll" />
  <Target Name="Migrate">
    <Message Text="Migrating database" />
    <Migrate Database="sqlserver" Connection="YOUR CONNECTION STRING" Target="$(IntermediateOutputPath)YOUR DLL NAME.dll">
    </Migrate>
  </Target>
```

Also make sure the target is added after the Build target like so:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build;Migrate;Test" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

You may have noticed that I load the msbuild task from the project directory.  I copied the **FluentMigrator.MSBuild.dll AND the FluentMigrator.Runner.dll** assemblies into my project folder.  When I tried to load the assemblies from the packages folder I got an error saying the assemblies were not in the correct format...